# llbd error on Xcode 4.6

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I am making a Website Picker App on Xcode 4.6 and there are no issues except when I try to run it I get send to the debugger with an error.

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([Website_PickerAppDelegate class]));
```

^^This is highlighted in green with Thread 1: signal SIGABRT under it.

It also has:

```
2013-06-06 23:29:53.698 Website Picker[1185:c07] -[Website_PickerViewController pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75614f0
2013-06-06 23:29:53.699 Website Picker[1185:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Website_PickerViewController pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75614f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1d1d4bd 0x1c81bbc 0x1c8194e 0xc691 0xf41a 0x1f8548 0x1fb224 0xbf952
 0xbf2dc 0xdff8 0x642dd 0x10e36b0 0x228efc0 0x228333c 0x228eeaf 0x1032bd 0x4bb56 0x4a66f 0x4a589
 0x497e4 0x4961e 0x4a3d9 0x4d2d2 0xf799c 0x44574 0x4476f 0x44905 0x4d917 0x234b 0x11157 0x11747 
 0x1294b 0x23cb5 0x24beb 0x16698 0x1beddf9 0x1bedad0 0x1c07bf5 0x1c07962 0x1c38bb6 0x1c37f44 
 0x1c37e1b 0x1217a 0x13ffc 0x2052 0x1f85)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Can someone please tell me what is the problem ?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably exists because `Website_PickerAppDelegate` is the class name and not the variable name, unless you capitalize your variable names. It needs to be something like

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([pickerAppDeligateVar class]));
```

Of course replace `pickerAppDeligateVar` with the appropriate variable name and give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
-[Website_PickerViewController pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75614f0
```

means that you did not implement the

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

method in the `Website_PickerViewController` that acts as data source for the picker view.

(If you think that you implemented it: Check for typing errors such as upper/lower case
letters in the method name.)

Comment: Thank you so much!! One of my rows of code had picketview instead of picker view lol. Glad you told me to check typing errors!!

Comment: @user2462154: I'm glad that it helped and welcome to stackoverflow! (Note that you can "accept" answers by clicking on the check mark.)